# How to hide the product price for all the pages in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.2, magento2.3.3

**I have created one module and it has system configuration on the admin side, where the admin has the functionality to enable/disable the module. As per system configuration, `I need to hide the price from every place on the front end.`**

> i.e. "catalog, category, wish-list, a related product, up-sell products, cart, checkout, orders, email, account dashboard, etc.."

from everywhere `I need to hide the price if the module is enabled.`

Is there any global file for the price which can be overridden and add the code for `hiding price?`

I found one file, But if we override `\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox` and change in `wrapResult()` function, it works but it will affect only product page and home page `not for wish-list and other places.`

**how can I `achieve` this functionality? Is anyone have any idea about it?**

Answer (score 1):

You will want to create an after plugin on this interface method definition: `\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBoxRenderInterface::renderAmount`.

You can achieve this by declaring this plugin in a app/etc/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/frontend/di.xml file like it's described here: 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#declaring-a-plugin

your plugin should look something like that:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin;

class PriceBoxRenderDisabler {
    public function afterRenderAmount(
         \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBoxRenderInterface $subject,
         $result
    ) {
        //instead of assigning true fetch a value from the config
        $disabled = true;
        if($disabled) {
            return '';
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

After that make sure to run:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: its not woking please share the exact code and folder structure since i'm new to magento.

Answer (score 0):

Below code hide price from all location whether it is listing page, single product page , compare or wishlist etc.

File path: app/code/Solwin/Module1/view/base/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool" name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\PriceBox</item>
                <item name="default_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/default.phtml</item>
                <item name="default_amount_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount</item>
                <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Solwin_Module1::catalog/product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="special_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/special_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="tier_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/tier_prices.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox</item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="custom_option_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="configured_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\ConfiguredPriceBox</item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/configured_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</layout>
```

File Path: app/code/Solwin/Module1/view/base/templates/catalog/product/price/amount/default.phtml

Add below code in it or make it as blank:

```
<?php echo ""; ?>
```